# ListView delete line with matching field

Tags: vb.net, listview

i have a listview like the following:

```
Name  | Gender | Age
---------------------
Name1 |   XX   | 23
Name2 |   XY   | 21
Name3 |   XY   | 25
Name4 |   XX   | 30
```

When the listview gets filled, it creates entries of a combobox like this:

```
If Not ComboBox4.Items.Contains(gender) Then
    ComboBox4.Items.Add(gender)
End If
```

So I end up with a combobox with 2 entries (XX, XY). Now i want to delete all **lines** matching to the gender selected in the combobox. The seleted entry then gets removed from the combobox.
Example: I select gender 'XX' to be removed, then the program removes the whole line with 'name1, XX , age 23' and 'name4, XX, 30' from the listview.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    for i = 1 to viewlist.items.count
        'Need help here to select the right column/viewlist-field
    next
    ComboBox4.Items.Remove(ComboBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your loop should start at `viewlist.Items.Count - 1` and end at `0`. This is because the right side of `To` is only evaluated prior to the first iteration. Due to this the loop will go to whatever `viewlist.Items.Count - 1` was **before** the loop was run, instead of what it actually is after removing items (hence why you got the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` from my previous code).

By starting from the end and going towards 0 `i` will always represent a valid index as long as you remove at most one item per iteration. This can be illustrated by the following:

```
First iteration    Second iteration    Third iteration    (and so on)
    Item 0             Item 0              Item 0
    Item 1             Item 1          (i) Item 1
    Item 2         (i) Item 2              [Removed]
(i) Item 3             [Removed]           [Removed]
```

Now, to get a sub-column of an item you can use the [**`ListViewItem.SubItems` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx). Your `Gender` column is currently at index 1 - the first sub-item (index 0) is apparently the owner of all sub-items, that is, the original `ListViewItem`.

```
For i = viewlist.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim CurrentSubItems As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection = viewlist.Items(i).SubItems
    If CurrentSubItems.Count >= 2 AndAlso CurrentSubItems(1).Text = ComboBox4.Text Then
        viewlist.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
ComboBox4.Items.Remove(ComboBox4.Text)
```

If you want to use case-insensitive string comparison you can change the `If`-statement in the loop to:

```
If CurrentSubItems.Count >= 2 AndAlso String.Equals(CurrentSubItems(1).Text, ComboBox4.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

Comment: This throws the exception "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" with additional information: InvalidArgument=Value with value 1 for index is invalid.

Comment: @neverlucky : That's odd... What's the value of `i` when the exception is thrown? The only explanation I can come up with would be that you have a `ListViewItem` with no sub-items.

Comment: Whenever i try to `Msgbox(viewlist.items.count)` it shows a number way larger than the amount of entries in the viewlist really are. Is it possible to ignore `ListViewItem` without sub-items?

Comment: Are you sure this works? The program now always counts `3` (horizontally) through `viewlist.Items(i).SubItems` instead the number of entries (vertically). So it always shows `3`, no matter how much XX oder XY persons I add. Is this right? Even if I have 20 entries, it deletes only 3 because it just reads the amount of columns (I hope you understand what i mean)

Comment: @neverlucky : I'm not sure what you mean, no... I haven't tested the code yet due to the fact that I don't have access to a computer, but the code checks so that there are at least two sub-items (0: the owner, 1: the `Gender` column) and should remove each item where the `Gender` column is what you selected in the `ComboBox`. -- I'll be able to try this in soon though.

Comment: @neverlucky : Ok, I found the problem and have updated the answer with code and an explanation of what went wrong.

Comment: @neverlucky : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!